# Google Maps polygoncomplete listener is not firing

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Here is the exact copy of my code. For some reason the "polygoncomplete" function is not firing at all when I complete the creation of a poly. This line is at the very end of the javascript. Any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        .controls {
            margin-top: 10px;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            height: 32px;
            outline: none;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        }

        #pac-input {
            background-color: #fff;
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 300;
            margin-left: 12px;
            padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            width: 300px;
        }

        #pac-input:focus {
            border-color: #4d90fe;
        }

        .pac-container {
            font-family: Roboto;
        }

        #type-selector {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #4d90fe;
            padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
        }

        #type-selector label {
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
        #target {
            width: 345px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Places Searchbox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        function initAutocomplete() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: 41.850033, lng: -98.6500523},
                zoom: 4,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            // Initialize Draw Tool
            var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
                drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
                drawingControl: true,
                drawingControlOptions: {
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                    drawingModes: [
                        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
                        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
                        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
                        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
                    ]
                },
                markerOptions: {icon: 'images/beachflag.png'},
                circleOptions: {
                    fillColor: '#ffff00',
                  fillOpacity: 1,
                  strokeWeight: 5,
                  clickable: false,
                  editable: true,
                  zIndex: 1
                }
            });
            drawingManager.setMap(map);

            // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
            var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

            // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
            map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
                searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
            });

            var markers = [];
            // [START region_getplaces]
            // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
            // more details for that place.
            searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
                var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

                if (places.length == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                // Clear out the old markers.
                markers.forEach(function(marker) {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                });
                markers = [];

                // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                places.forEach(function(place) {
                    var icon = {
                        url: place.icon,
                        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                    };

                    // Create a marker for each place.
                    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        icon: icon,
                        title: place.name,
                        position: place.geometry.location
                    }));

                    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                        // Only geocodes have viewport.
                        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                    }
                    else{
                        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                    }
                });
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            });
            // [END region_getplaces]
            google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
                var coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray());
                console.log(coordinates);
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,drawing&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
</body>
```

Comment: for me the listener works as expected

Comment: Wow, I was using draw line the entire time to draw my polygons. It helps to use the Draw Polygon button instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are using the Draw Poly option and not Draw Line.